# Php returning text between ?> <?

Tags: php, return

How can I return text between `?>` and `<?`?

For example:

```
<?php
  function generateCode(){
     return ?> TEXT HERE  <?
  }
?>
```

For what I've seen it just prints it on the screen. Is there any way to return that text?

Comment: You can use ob_start();  and ob_get_clean();

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, why exactly do you want to use this over just regular old `return 'foo';` ?

Comment: well, even if it worked the way you wrote it, you would need to end the statement still with a semi colon, wouldn't you  <?;

Comment: @Joeroen Smitt Because this is going to return js code with "", and I don't want to use \"

Comment: @Galunid `return '<script>alert("foo");</script>';` is perfectly valid. No \" involved.

Comment: @JeroenSmit return '<script>log("<span style=\'color: red\'>"+text+"</span>")</script>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words *No*,

text outside of PHP are concidered as plain html and is printed as is.

but you can even thou warp your HTML code in 'single' or "double" quotes .

if you have a multiple combination of both quotes you can use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

**Example:**

```
return <<<EOT
TEXT HERE
EOT;
```